# Mongodb update with arrayfilters | write exception: write errors: [Cannot apply array updates to non-array element groups: null]

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I have the following `employee` data structure :

```json
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"62836b0b3c1e2c19eaaac07e"
   },
   "firstname":"jean",
   "lastname":"paul",
   "email":"employee@test.co",
   "password":"d94307e0eabb9bba1ea1291e4b043175e11dcc43875a4858690e5c236b989f3e",
   "salt":"2CzpCiIbiyYcSxQ",
   "organizations":[
      {
         "organizationid":{
            "$oid":"62836aa93c1e2c19eaaac07d"
         },
         "organizationname":"test",
         "ismanager":false,
         "groups":[
            {
               "name":"mongroupe",
               "permissions":[
                  0,
                  2
               ]
            }
         ],
         "permissions":[
            1
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to build a function in go that adds a set of permissions to the `organizations.[x].groups.[x].permissions` array. Each `permission` is a simple integer.

I've come up with the following code :

```golang
func AddPermissionsToGroup(groupName string, organizationId primitive.ObjectID, permissions []global.Permission) error {
        if res, err := employeesCollection.UpdateMany(
        context.TODO(),
        bson.M{},
        bson.M{
            "$addToSet": bson.M{
                "organizations.$[org].groups.$[grp].permissions": bson.M{
                    "$each": permissions,
                },
            },
        },
        options.Update().SetArrayFilters(
            options.ArrayFilters{
                Filters: []interface{}{
                    bson.M{
                        "org.organizationid": organizationId,
                    },
                    bson.M{
                        "grp.name": groupName,
                    },
                },
            },
        ),
    ); res.MatchedCount == 0 {
        return global.ErrEntityNotFound
    } else if res.ModifiedCount == 0 {
        return global.ErrNoUpdateNeeded
    } else if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed updating employees | %s", err.Error())
    }
    return nil

}
```

The code returns the following error :  write exception: write errors: [Cannot apply array updates to non-array element groups: null].

I have no idea what it means.

Maybe the engine doesn't like the fact that I use two `ArrayFilter`s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i created this playground that works : https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tznz7btfLkH

Actually the issue was not because of the request itself that was valid syntaxically. It came from the fact i had another document in the `employee` collection that looked like this :

```json
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"62836aa93c1e2c19eaaac07c"
   },
   "firstname":"jean",
   "lastname":"charles",
   "email":"manager@test.co",
   "password":"6776c354fce809e7be234f84d0ea907cfd3aba350871a18858ceccc10eabc036",
   "salt":"IHaPJIKVVplC8ni",
   "organizations":[
      {
         "organizationid":{
            "$oid":"62836aa93c1e2c19eaaac07d"
         },
         "organizationname":"test",
         "ismanager":true,
         "groups":null,
         "permissions":null
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, the `groups` value is null here. And that is the problem.

Basically, when the arrayfilter named `grp` meets a null object, it raises an error because it can't apply on it.

So the solution to make the request work was to make sure every document in the collection had this `group` array initialized (even if it's empty, it doesn't matter). Once I did this there was no problem anymore.